# Magento, add calculated custom field to query for later use

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to add a custom column on a query. I have seen many SO questions related to add a custom column on a grid, that is not a problem. But I can not manage to add a new field on a select clause that is not present on my model. Here is my code:

I have this snippet from my `_prepareCollection()` function:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('banners/bannersadmin')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
        ->join(array("T"=>$this->_bannersadminTable), "main_table.banner_start_date BETWEEN T.banner_start_date AND T.banner_end_date", array())
        ->where("main_table.bannerID < T.bannerID");

    var_dump((string) $collection->getselect());
```

The resulting query is the following one:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*
  FROM `dts_banners_admin` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `dts_banners_admin` AS `T`
    ON main_table.banner_start_date BETWEEN T.banner_start_date AND T.banner_end_date
 WHERE (main_table.bannerID < T.bannerID)
```

But I need this slightly different result, with the `aux_value` column added with a value of my own, 1 on this case but could be anything else I want.

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, 1 AS `aux_value`
  FROM `dts_banners_admin` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `dts_banners_admin` AS `T`
    ON main_table.banner_start_date BETWEEN T.banner_start_date AND T.banner_end_date
 WHERE (main_table.bannerID < T.bannerID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `Zend_Db_Select::columns()` method in conjunction with `Zend_Db_Expr` class. For example:

```
$select->columns(array(
    'my_value' => new Zend_Db_Expr('1')
));
```

Comment: Already tried, will give it a shoot again...it works! Seems my previous tests were not correct. Thanks, I was really stuck with it.

Comment: What about if I wanted to modify this value inside the query? I mean, once it is executed, instead of `1` I want to output `2`?

Comment: I think you can use `$select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)` - this will return all columns from $select object. Try to modify them and set again using `$select->columns($yourArray)`